# IPC Fifo buffer size

Tags: c++, c, buffer, ipc, fifo

Thank you for your help.

I am developing two programs in C and C++ that communicate with interprocess communication based on FIFO files generated with mkfifo() by the first program. The communication works fine but it seems to be too slow it takes about 2 seconds to be read. I think that the buffer size of the fifo (by default on Squeeze 6 Debian Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 65336 bytes) is to big how can I reduce it ?

By the way I have tried to find this file **/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size** but unfortunatly it is not present on my system  (shall I create it ?). (src="https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer")

Comment: You can pump quite a few hundres of megabytes through a fifo in a second, so what exactly takes 2 seconds ? The buffer size is unlikely the fault here.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide any code snippet. Nonetheless, I'd suggest you take a look at [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#fifos) and  [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node15.html#SECTION00730000000000000000) if you're new to Unix IPCs.